# calling wcf service on localhost

Tags: jquery, wcf

```
function CallWcfService(str, AppName) 
{

var list = ["a"];

jQuery.support.cors = true;
jQuery.ajax({

    type: "POST",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    url: 'http://192.168.2.20/CWSERVERWCF/MainLoginService.svc/GetSubModuleTotalCountByUserAppNo',
    data: JSON.stringify({ strErrMsg: list, chrErrFlg: 'Y', pcocd: sessionStorage.getItem("CoCd"), pdiv: sessionStorage.getItem("Div"), ploc: sessionStorage.getItem("Loc"), UserId: username, ShowParameter: sessionStorage.getItem("Parameter"), AppNo: sessionStorage.getItem("AppNo") }),
    dataType: "json",
    processData: false,
    crossDomain: true,
    success: function (r) {
        ServiceSucceeded(r)
    },
    error: ServiceFailed// When Service call fails
});
```

}

I am trying to call web service but whenever i am calling using localhost instead of ip address i am facing error..please help

Comment: can you please describe the error you are getting ?

Comment: nothing is happening..web service not getting call

Answer (score 0):

Localhost can only be used if service is hosted on IIS of your machine, i mean the client and server machine should be same.To access remote services you should use IP or domain name if its on Internet or you can also use machine name if its on Intranet.

Comment: i got it..i want to use it on same machine only...do you have any idea what url i should use if i want to achieve this..i access the WCF directly in browser and using that URL in code..but after deployed on iis is is not working

Comment: one more thing i would like to add i have following code in interface  <System.ServiceModel.Web.WebInvoke(Method:="POST", _
        ResponseFormat:=System.ServiceModel.Web.WebMessageFormat.Json)> _